# python - concatenate two time series with different time stamps

Tags: python, pandas, time, concatenation

My question is exactly same with the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46666383/two-time-series-data-with-different-time-stamps-and-a-different-number-of-data-p.)

But, my language is Python, not R. So I ask this question again.

I have two time series with different time stamps and a different number of data points.

For example,

first data is

[image: image1]

second data is

[image: image2]

.

I concatenate two tables into one table.

I want to do two things. First, time index should be in order.

It is easily done by `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`. The result is

[image: image3]

The second thing is to replace 'NA' by the most recent data point.

For example, at time 0.1, the value of column 'B' is 2.1 which is the value at time 0.09. In a same manner, the value of columns 'A' at time 0.30 should be 3.0. But still, there is no value at time 0.09 for columns 'A'.

How can I do this second job?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't post pictures of your example data. Please provide a [mcve]. Refer to this post on how to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `fillna` with method ffill (forward fill)

```
>>> df.fillna(method='ffill')
         A     B
0.09   NaN   2.1
0.10   2.0   2.1
0.22   3.0   3.3
0.30   3.0   5.1
0.33   5.0   5.1
0.50   4.0   4.0
0.59   4.0  10.0
0.60  10.0  10.0
```

if you want to reassign this to the same dataframe, set parameter inplace=True

Comment: You can also just chain it on to concat: `df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).ffill()`