# Bash Command To Do a Column Merge of Two csv files With Different Time-Series Rows

Tags: bash, csv, merge, time-series

I have two csv files with Time-Series data, and I want to do a column merge on them using bash. The merge part is simple `paste -d , file1.csv file2.csv > combined.csv` produces a merged file with the extra columns.

The problem is that the time series data from each file doesn't line up and I want to be able to handle that situation. So the merged rows are aligned by the timestamp in column A.

This same problem is described in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18669514/merge-two-time-series-with-different-time-granularities). But that was related to the R programming language, so the answer doesn't work for bash.

```
# File 1                                      # File 2
| Time                 | Datapoint |          | Time                 | Datapoint |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:00Z | 43        |          | 2021-04-01T00:00:05Z | 51        |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:01Z | 44        |          | 2021-04-01T00:00:10Z | 52        |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:02Z | 45        |          | 2021-04-01T00:00:15Z | 53        |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:03Z | 46        |          | 2021-04-01T00:00:20Z | 54        |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:04Z | 47        |          | 2021-04-01T00:00:25Z | 55        |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:05Z | 48        |          | 2021-04-01T00:00:30Z | 56        |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:06Z | 49        |          | 2021-04-01T00:00:35Z | 57        |

# Desired File
| Time                 | Datapoint | Datapoint |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:00Z | 43        |           |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:01Z | 44        |           |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:02Z | 45        |           |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:03Z | 46        |           |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:04Z | 47        |           |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:05Z | 48        | 51        |
| 2021-04-01T00:00:06Z | 49        |           |
```

I know I can write a script to read both files, and write the data related to each timestamp seperately. But I wondered if there was another way of doing this using bash utilities?

Comment: `join -t, -a1 -j1 file1 file2` should work if your files are actual CSVs (i.e, fields are separated by commas), and timestamps are sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join`. This requires sorted files, but from the looks of it your files are already sorted.

[`join --header -t, -j1 -a1 file1 file2`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=join%20--header%20-t%2C%20-j1%20-a1%20file1%20file2) prints

```
Time                ,Datapoint,Datapoint
2021-04-01T00:00:00Z,43
2021-04-01T00:00:01Z,44
2021-04-01T00:00:02Z,45
2021-04-01T00:00:03Z,46
2021-04-01T00:00:04Z,47
2021-04-01T00:00:05Z,48       ,51
2021-04-01T00:00:06Z,49
```